# Why gcc throws "error: aggregate value used" error for struct but not for integer arrays?

Tags: c, gcc, low-level

gcc is able to compile with no problems
if I try to assign the address of global integer array into a field a global struct
as you can see in the snippet below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int integer_array[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};

struct my_struct {
        uintptr_t addr;
};

struct my_struct s = {
        .addr = (uintptr_t)t
};


int main() {
        printf("0x%lx\n", s.addr);
}
```

However, If I modify the above code and instead of an array I pass a structure, gcc is throwing
the following error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct test {
        int integer_array[4];
};
struct test t;

struct my_struct {
        uintptr_t addr;
};

struct my_struct s = {
        .addr = (uintptr_t)t
};


int main() {
        printf("0x%lx\n", s.addr);
}
```

```
test.c:15:1: error: aggregate value used where an integer was expected
   15 | };
```

Can anybody explain to me why this is happening ?

Comment: In `(uintptr_t)t`, the name of an array implicitly converts to a pointer to the first element.  That's not the case for a struct, you'd need `&t`.  Also, your first code block uses `t`, an identifier only your 2nd code block defines.

Comment: @PeterCordes it is because structs can be assigned - thus no decay